# setInterval won't call function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create a sort of ecosystem where objects spawn over time. However, when I try using setInterval to increase the amount it doesn't work. It works when I call the function on its own, but not when I use setInterval.

```
var plantSpawn = 5;

function createPlants() {

    setInterval(reproducePlants, 5000);

    for(var i=0; i<plantSpawn; i++){

        var plant = new Object();
            plant.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            plant.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
            plant.rad = 2;
            plant.skin = 'green';

        myPlants[i] = plant;

    }
}   

function reproducePlants() {
    plantSpawn += 5;
}
```

My goal for this is for every 5 seconds, 5 new plants appear. However, when I use the reproducePlants function with setInterval it does not work.

Note: I am calling createPlants() later in my code which makes the first 5 plants show up, but the next 5 won't show up. I am just showing the code that I'm trying to fix

Comment: You need to call `createPlants` to actually create plants, incrementing a number variable by itself won't ever do anything

Comment: function reproducePlants() { createPlants() }

Comment: Hi Jason, If I understood what you are trying to accomplish, I think you need to move the code that creates the plants (the for() chunck) inside the function that is called every 5 seconds. So each time the function is called it will create the plants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation code must be moved inside the function that is repeatedly called.

NOTE: This is not an efficient way if you are going to call reproducePlants infinitely many times, since the myPlants array is reconstructed every time.

```
// Init with 0, because we increment it inside reproduce Plants
var plantSpawn = 0;
var myPlants = [];

function createPlants() {
    reproducePlants();
    setInterval(reproducePlants, 5000);
}   

function reproducePlants() {
    const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    plantSpawn += 5;

    for(var i = 0; i < plantSpawn; i++) {
        var plant = new Object();
        plant.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        plant.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
        plant.rad = 2;
        plant.skin = 'green';

        myPlants[i] = plant;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped create more plants! I do see what you are saying as the array is reconstructed every time. I will look for alternative ways to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to call the `createPlants` function from the `reproducePlants` function. You could add a call after both the functions. If I understand what you are trying to achieve that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code that creates the plants (the for() chunck) inside the function that is called every 5 seconds (reproduce plants). So each time the function is called it will create the plants.

If you are trying to add only the 5 new plants every 5 seconds to your plants array you shouldn't recreate the array each time. It's better to keep track of the last index you have added and then continue right after that.

I created a variable called `lastCreatedIndex` so you can understand better what is going on. So the first time the code will run `plants[i]` from 0 to 4, the second 5 to 9...

```
var myPlants = [];
var lastCreatedIndex;
var plantSpawn;


function createPlants() {
    plantSpawn = 5; //Initialize with 5 plants
    lastCreatedIndex = 0; // Starts from index 0
    reproducePlants();
    setInterval(reproducePlants, 5000);
}   

function reproducePlants() {

    for(var i = 0 + lastCreatedIndex; i < plantSpawn; i++) {
        var plant = new Object();
        plant.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        plant.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
        plant.rad = 2;
        plant.skin = 'green';

        myPlants[i] = plant;
        console.log(i); // Output the number of the plant that has been added
    }
    lastCreatedIndex = i; //Update the last index value
    plantSpawn += 5;
}
```